# add active class On react with out state and toggle using JS dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I'm trying to add Active Class in React using JS dom, but it doesn't work for me
Please help in finding the solution. Please give a complete solution that includes the code with a little explanation because I feel that I am confused in dealing with the Dom

```
<FilterOrder>
   <div className=""  onClick={ActiveClass}> Today      </div>
   <div className=""  onClick={ActiveClass}> Yesterday  </div>
   <div className=""  onClick={ActiveClass}> This Week  </div>
```

My Function =>

```
const ActiveClass=(e)=>{
const active=e.target.classList;
const prevActive=document.getElementsByClassName("Active");
prevActive.forEach((e)=>console.log("hello"));
active.classList.add("Active");
}
```

error =>

[image]

Answer (score 0):

DOM mutation is very anti-pattern in React. Use React refs to get access to underlying DOMNodes, or just toggle the classnames the React way using some local state.

This said, the error is caused by `getElementsByClassName` returning some collection that isn't an actual `Array`, it returns a [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), which is an array-like structure.

There is no `forEach` method to invoke. You can use `Array.from` if you want/need to iterate the returned elements.

```
const ActiveClass = (e) => {
  const active = e.target.classList;
  const prevActive = document.getElementsByClassName("Active");

  Array.from(prevActive).forEach((e) => console.log("hello"));

  active.classList.add("Active");
}
```